# In Selenium using Java the program is not clicking on the element (NoSuchElementException)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new to `Selenium`, I am writing a code to work in `IE`. I fetch the properties from `Mozilla` using `Firebug` then run the program in `IE` (client specific). There is one element for which even after recording its xpath selenium is not able to perform operation on it. The object is visible on the screen still compiler is throwing (NoSuchElementException) and the code fails. This element doesn't have id, class or name and need to be addressed by "xpath" or "linktext".
Here is my code:

```
 do
        {
        if(D.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='popUpDiv-tpl']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a[2]/span")).isDisplayed())
        {
            WebElement confirm_button = D.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='popUpDiv-tpl']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a[2]/span"));
            confirm_button.click();
            flag = 0;
          try {
                synchronized (D) {
                    D.wait(5000);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            D.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            flag = 1;
        }
        }while(flag == 1);
```

I use this code, so that my code will wait till the object is loaded and then perform the required operation.

This code works fine for all other elements however not for this

Comment: Please provide the html. Also I see the element already has id. Unless this is dynamic not sure why you are using xpath?

Answer (score 0):

The code above should work if the xpaths are correct. I am doubting that it is not working because your application might be doing a ajax call.

If it is doing an ajax call then try using

```
Thread.sleep(2000L);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above code you had the Id and i think it is not dynamic. First try with Id